# react method is not a function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a nested return within a map. My error is renderTooltip is not a function, below is my code.

```
renderTooltip = () => {
  return(
    <div>tooltip content</div>
  )
}

render() {
    const data = this.props.data || {};

    return (
      <div>
        {data && data.applicants.map((e,i) => {
              return (<span key={i}>
                {e.date_type === 'something' ? this.renderTooltip(e.company_info) : ''}
                </span>)
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: It works as expected , check whether you get a correct data

Comment: your `render` and `renderTooltip` are part of the same component class right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a React component class? The below component works fine:

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    renderTooltip = () => {
        return(
            <div>tooltip content</div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        const data = this.props.data || {applicants: [{date_type: 'something', id: 'a'}, {date_type: 'something', id: 'b'}]};
        return (
            <div>
                {data && data.applicants.map((e,i) => {
                    return (<span key={i}>
                {e.date_type === 'something' ? this.renderTooltip(e.company_info) : ''}
                </span>)
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```